# Nagiosgraph throwing error

Tags: nagios

When trying to open any graph on Nagios throws below error:

Nagiosgraph has detected an error in the configuration file: /etc/nagios/nagiosgraph/nagiosgraph.conf
Log: /var/log/nagios/nagiosgraph.log failed to open!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that permissions are set properly on `/var/log/nagios`

the www (or www-data or apache) user must have write permission.

one approach is to make a group called nagcmd and put the www user into this group.

then set permissions:

```
chown nagios.nagcmd /var/log/nagios
chown nagios.www /var/log/nagios/nagiosgraph.log
chmod 775 /var/log/nagios
chmod 664 /var/log/nagios/nagiosgraph.log
```

another approach is to keep separate log files, one for data collection (nagiosgraph.log) and another for graphing (nagiosgraph-cgi.log).  see nagiosgraph.conf for details.